# Firefox OS app get contacts from gmail

Tags: javascript, gmail, contacts, firefox-os

I'm gonna develop a firefox os app and I need to get/modify/create contacts from gmail; obviously I'd need a js script to do that but every example I've got by gmail/stack overflow/google didn't work to me... could anyone of you guide me to retrieve the contact list?

The best example I've found is this:

```
<!--Add a button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var clientId = 'my client id';

      var apiKey = 'my api';

      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

      function handleClientLoad() {
        // Step 2: Reference the API key
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
      }

      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          makeApiCall();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        // Step 3: get authorization to use private data
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
      function makeApiCall() {
        // Step 4: Load the Google+ API
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
          // Step 5: Assemble the API request
          var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
          });
          // Step 6: Execute the API request
          request.execute(function(resp) {
            var heading = document.createElement('h4');
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = resp.image.url;
            heading.appendChild(image);
            heading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.displayName));

            document.getElementById('content').appendChild(heading);
          });
        });
      }
    </script>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

The problem is that this code never enters the handleAuthResult(authResult) function and I get no js errors...

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you tried, what didn't work, and what errors, and problems you got please?